# How can I return a list from a given start and end point

Tags: python, list

I want to create a function that imports a list and start and end index and returns the list from the start and end. Here is what I have so far.

```
def listIndex(string, start, end):
    string = string[start:end]
    return string
```

but right now the list stays the same when I use the function. Here is my test code.

```
string = ["name1","name2","name3","name4"]
listIndex(string, 0 , 1)
print(string)
```

And this is the output I get
['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']
When I wanted to get
['name1','name2']

Comment: You called the function?

Comment: could you please add the current output..?

Comment: That's totally legit function, check in other places for trouble, it returns what you would expect, unless you expect it to modify preexisting sequence.

Comment: Your code will not modify the original argument. It simply creates a second, local variable named `string`. The original `string` stays the same.

Comment: The function is returning some value so you should store it in a variable then print it..

Answer (score 0):

```
string ="stackoverflow"
start = 1
end = 12
string = listIndex(string, start, end)
```

Output,string = "tackoverflo"
you can also use:

```
string = string[1:-1]
```